# Database required for standalone application

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I am constructing a standalone application that is comprised of HTML, CSS and JS files.  The data that is being used by the application is being loaded from an XML file.

I, however, require the application to use a local database - something that would allow me to  load, create and edit the data in this database using Javascript.  Then package up the application and send it on (I am using webapp-xul-wrapper for this).

Could anybody give me some advice on how I could achieve this? The majority of solutions I have looked at use local storage or only keep the db table data for that particular session or require server side code.

To clarify, my application has a settings page that I would like to allow to edit my data and then keep that data persistent so that when the application is opened again the data is intact.  Furthermore, if I was to send the application to someone else - that data would also be intact.  Ideally my app would take its data from a physical file that could be passed around.

I hope this question makes sense!

Many thanks,

G.

Comment: Where does your Javascript interpreter run?

Comment: Within this wrapper https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using a packager called TideSDK (http://www.tidesdk.org/) which supports SQLLite out of the box and also seems to render my applications layout much clearer.

Many thanks!